# Android emulator doesnt start in microsoft hosted agents whenever cpu is i7

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, android-emulator

Below is my bash script from my yml, that starts android emulator which is used for UI tests

```
`echo "Agent Specifications:"
          echo "---------------------"
          sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string  
          sysctl -n hw.memsize                
          sysctl -n hw.ncpu
          echo "---------------------"
          echo "Creating emulator"
          echo "y" | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --install 'system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86'
          echo "no" | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/avdmanager create avd -n android_emulator -k 'system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86' --force
          $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -list-avds
          echo "Starting emulator"
          nohup $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd android_emulator -wipe-data -memory 8192 -skin 1080x1920 -no-snapshot -no-audio -no-boot-anim -accel auto -gpu auto -qemu -lcd-density 420 &
          echo "<><><>checking if emulator has started<><><>"
          $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d ''\r'') ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
          $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices
          echo "Emulator started"`
```

Recently I came across situation where android emulator doesn't more than half of the times.
So I started debugging, but dev logs didn't help, as it was same for the one where emulator started, and where it didnt start.
Later on i added lines to print cpu, ram and memory, and observed:
As I am using microsoft hosted agents : I am randomly allocated below 2 cpu :
1)Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz
2)Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700B CPU @ 3.20GHz

Whenever cpu is 2)Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700B CPU @ 3.20GHz , emulator doesnt start.
and if cpu is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz iy starts normally.

Can anyone help here?

Os is macOs-12

Tried changing Os image , didnt help. Couldn't find the way in azure to specify cpu for hosted agents.

Comment: Hi there, Can you please check the bash script suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops#test-on-the-android-emulator) to create emulator and if it works for your app? You may consider testing with a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/osx-agent?view=azure-devops) as a workaround or to isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi Alvin, Yes I have tried using same script, doesn't help. Also, I do not want to use self hosted agent.